# how do i transform a HashMap[T,Future[N]] to Future[HashMap[T,N]]

Tags: scala, future

I know that there exists

```
Future.sequence
```

to transform a `List[Future[T]]` to a `Future[List[T]]`

is there any way to transform a `HashMap[T,Future[N]]` to `Future[HashMap[T,N]]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't anything built into the standard libraries for this, but it's easy enough to implement, e.g.

```
def combineFutures[K,V](m: Map[K,Future[V]]): Future[Map[K,V]] = {
    m.foldLeft(Future.successful(Map.empty[K, V])) {
        case (futureAcc: Future[Map[K, V]], (k: K, futureV: Future[V])) =>
            for {
                acc <- futureAcc
                v <- futureV
            } yield acc + (k -> v)
    }
}

// Mutable HashMap version
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
def combineFutures[K,V](m: HashMap[K,Future[V]]): Future[HashMap[K,V]] = {
    m.foldLeft(Future.successful(HashMap.empty[K, V])) {
        case (futureAcc: Future[HashMap[K, V]], (k: K, futureV: Future[V])) =>
            for {
                acc <- futureAcc
                v <- futureV
            } yield {
                acc.put(k, v)
                acc
            }
    }
}
```

(I've added some extra unnecessary type annotations above for clarity.)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about an out-of-the-box function, but I'd do it myself like this:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val a: HashMap[Int, Future[Int]] = HashMap((1, Future(42)), (2, Future(43)))
val iterOfFutures = a.map { case (k, v) => v.map(vv => (k, vv)) }
val futureMap: Future[Map[Int, Int]] = Future.sequence(iterOfFutures).map(_.toMap)

futureMap.map(println) // Map(2 -> 43, 1 -> 42)
Thread.sleep(100)
```

**EDIT:**

Not the main point of the question, but if you want a mutable HashMap instead of immutable Map then you have to convert it. Here's an ugly-ish way off the top of my head, perhaps there's something nicer:

```
val futureMap: Future[HashMap[Int, Int]] = 
  Future.sequence(iterOfFutures).map(s => HashMap(s.toSeq: _*))
```